# How to set text of a textbox to JSON value? C#

Tags: c#, json, api, twitch

I made a C# program to select a twitch streamer and it will tell me if theyre live or not then I press a button to watch them. I am trying to add a box that will show me the current game before i watch them too. Here is the code I have that tells me if theyre live or not:

```
chan = chan.Replace(" ", "");
String json_data = w.DownloadString("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + chan);
JObject stream = JObject.Parse(json_data);

if (stream["stream"].HasValues)
{
    textBox4.Text = "LIVE";
    textBox4.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    textBox4.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
}
else
{
    textBox4.Text = "OFFLINE";
    textBox4.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    textBox4.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
}
```

I want to take the JSON data from twitch and take the value of "game" and output it to a text box. Here is a example of what twitch JSON data looks like.

[Twitch JSON data](http://pastebin.com/nRp92hyd)

I dont know how to output that specific value to the textbox. Do I do stream.game?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json_data);

var stream = obj["stream"];

if (stream.HasValues)
{
    ....

    var game = stream["game"];

    JValue game_jvalue = game as JValue;

    if (game_jvalue != null)
    {
        string game_value = game_jvalue.Value.ToString();
        //use game_value here
    }

}
else
{
    ....
}
```